# How to notify moderators about repeated invalid edits

Tags: discussion, vandalism, trolling

There is an user that continue to vandalize posts. He hasn't enough reputation to modify posts, but he's still trying to do it(I've reject at least 3 suggested edits for vandalism in the last few minutes).

He has never post an answer nor a question, so I can't flag none of it's post in order to signal his troll-like behavior to moderators.

It's not a big problem, but it's quite annoying.

How should we behave in this or similar cases?
How can we notify moderators about that?

Comment: If enough of his edits get rejected, the system will automatically ban him from editing.

Comment: @hammar: good to know. I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can flag for moderator attention one of the posts where you've rejected an edit, choose other, and explain the situation.

Comment: A link to a rejected edit would help.

Comment: @Bart I suspect it wasn't included to avoid exposing the user.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Meh, given the overall contributions...but deleted. Won't can still see it though.

Comment: If you are going to fix it @won't would you mind review banning everyone who approved those edits..?

Comment: There was one approver of those edits...

Comment: @Bart true, but I think it is a good policy in general to not expose users when practical, regardless of their contributions. Not that it is hard to go figure out who they are *probably* talking about...

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yep, fair enough

Comment: @benisuqbackwards: Only one guy I saw approved.  Twice.  He's review banned for a month now.  And the editor is now the former editor.  Poof.